# Circuit to harvest power

Tags: energy-harvesting, charge-pump

I am working with a homemade material. I can harvest a power from this system. Thus a load, plugged to short cut my material, is crossed by a current. I would like to really harvest this power, it means to keep it and use it when i want. Is a charge pump circuit a good system ? What kind of easy circuit can I use ?

Thanks, I am a chemist....[image]

Comment: There are no easy harvesting circuits, because harvesting isn't easy. Check out the various harvesting solutions from IC manufacturers.

Comment: What is the nature of the power that you'd like to harvest?  For example: mechanical, thermal gradient, photovoltaic, radio.  [At the moment, you question is interesting but vague.  You'd have to add more information before we can start answering it.  I used to be a chemist too, by the way.]

Comment: It sounds as though a voltage is generated. What voltage? What current?

Comment: thanks for your interest. I have loaded a picture, to well understand the situation

Comment: I don't have enough experience to answer, but I know that there are lots of ICs that can use this to charge up a supercapacitor or a small battery. You seem to get a decent amount of current, and 0.4 volts isn't *that* low.

Answer (score 3):

To get some experience with harvesting circuits you could try something like this (taken from the [datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3105fb.pdf)):
[image]

In this case a thermoelectric generator is used but it should also work with your system.

In case you have more money than time, they also sell an [evaluation board](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?keywords=DC2042A-ND):
(otherwise use a [break-out](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/chip-quik-inc/IPC0078/IPC0078-ND/5014744) board)
[image]